# Unable to find CD-ROM

Tags: installation

I've tried installing msoffice 2007 using playonlinux but it is unable to find cdrom please suggest any idea to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have the disc space available, try copying the CD to disc and point playonlinux to that location.